# What is the Best way to get raid of ci_sessions (in mysql db) from impacting performance so badly?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, rest, cloudflare-workers

Project info : We have a CodeIgniter (v3.1.11) Backend (CRUD + Rest Api) to serve content to our android app, It use to work pretty good until we got our user base grown to 500k+ and Mysql started to consume almost all the available resources and upon investigating we notices that ci_sessions table is been the bottleneck which before use to destroy automatically But, now they just keep on increasing to MILLIONS So, No matter how much we keep on adding resources to the server Mysql(specifically ci_sessions table) hunger is just being never ending and This issue lead to complete disaster (we use to get around 10k+ new users registration/day and Now is barley around 1k and users retention has fallen from 79% to 15% which ultimately impacted revenue fall by 80 to 85%
We been able to keep existing users from being impacted By deploying edge cache server for read requests But, New users registrations are still being highly impacted

**So, Would it be safe to switch to Redis for session management and will there be any further changes required to the current way of how session management when using mysql database for storage.**

(I am a Android developer so I know most android dev would recommend that we should have preferred Firebase or similar service But, we had different scenario Firstly in our case success of project was not anticipate at least not in such short period of time With no promotional campaign and 0% web presence, we just got our app viral on some private community platform)

Comment: I doubt that rows just stored in ci_sessions is impacting your performance; are you saying it is queries selecting/updating ci_sessions that is the problem?

Comment: A database table with 500K rows is "small".  It sounds like the processing needs some indexes or better formulation.  Please provide the SQL queries that are causing the trouble.  Do not through further hardware or layers of processing at the problem; figure out the cause.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.